2sxc searchcontroller cannot find files or templates for some reason
In the DNN eventlog on a specific site I see a lot of errors with the searchcontroller for 2sxc (17.9). So in this example it says /Portals/0/2sxc/Content/bs5/Link/_List of anchors.cshtml does not exist, but there are also other template files that it says cannot be found.
I've checked, and the files do actually exist, so I guess it must be something else.
Any idea what might be the problem?
AbsoluteURL:

DefaultDataProvider:DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke

ExceptionGUID:f7316596-4839-4e9f-bb91-6b9acd08393b

AssemblyVersion:

PortalId:-1

UserId:-1

TabId:-1

RawUrl:

Referrer:

UserAgent:

ExceptionHash:TNj21OFxuCM2utbDlkm7ezYM2rs=

Message:Search: Error #9 of 10 in 'SearchController' while indexing module 3834 on tab 212, portal 0

StackTrace:

InnerMessage:The template file '/Portals/0/2sxc/Content/bs5/Link/_List of anchors.cshtml' does not exist.

InnerStackTrace:

   at ToSic.Sxc.Engines.EngineBase.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Init>b__0() in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Sxc\ToSic.Sxc\Engines\EngineBase.cs:line 88
   at ToSic.Lib.Logging.ILog_Actions.Do(ILog log, String parameters, Action action, Boolean timer, Boolean enabled, String message, String cPath, String cName, Int32 cLine) in C:\Projects\2sxc\eav-server\ToSic.Lib.Core\Logging\Log\ILog_Actions.cs:line 63
   at ToSic.Sxc.Engines.EngineBase.Init(IBlock block) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Sxc\ToSic.Sxc\Engines\EngineBase.cs:line 74
   at ToSic.Sxc.Engines.EngineBase.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<Init>b__0() in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Sxc\ToSic.Sxc\Engines\EngineBase_Old.cs:line 24
   at ToSic.Lib.Logging.ILog_Actions.Do(ILog log, String parameters, Action action, Boolean timer, Boolean enabled, String message, String cPath, String cName, Int32 cLine) in C:\Projects\2sxc\eav-server\ToSic.Lib.Core\Logging\Log\ILog_Actions.cs:line 63
   at ToSic.Sxc.Engines.EngineBase.Init(IBlock block, Purpose purpose) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Sxc\ToSic.Sxc\Engines\EngineBase_Old.cs:line 21
   at ToSic.Sxc.Search.SearchController.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<GetModifiedSearchDocuments>b__0(ILogCall l) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.Core\Dnn\Search\SearchController.cs:line 174
Source:

FileName:

FileLineNumber:0

FileColumnNumber:0

Method:

Server Name: wn0mdwk000AEF


I can't say much based on this. I recommend manually running the indexer and checking the insights right away to see what is being logged.
